# SQL statement to JTable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

I'd like to show all data out of a sqlite3 database inside of a JTable.
My result statement function looks like this:

```
public void getCustomerData()
  {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String ArrStrResult[][] = null;;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
      c.setAutoCommit(false);
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

      stmt = c.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM kunden");

      ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
      int numberOfColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();

      while(rs.next()){

         int id = rs.getInt("id");
         String  name = rs.getString("name");
         String vorname  = rs.getString("vorname");
         String  gebdatum = rs.getString("gebdatum");
         String strasse = rs.getString("strasse");
         System.out.println( "ID = " + id );
         System.out.println( "NAME = " + name );
         System.out.println( "VORNAME = " + vorname );
         System.out.println( "Geb.-Datum = " + gebdatum );
         System.out.println( "Straße = " + strasse );
         System.out.println();

      }
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Operation done successfully");


  }

}
```

In my MainWindow - class I'd like to have the result of the sql statement inside of a JTable which looks like this:

```
private void updateCustomerTable()
    {

        // Tabellengrundgerüst erstellen
        tableCustomer = new JTable();
        tableCustomer.setEnabled(false);
        tableCustomer.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        tableCustomer.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {,
            },
            new String[] {
                "Name:", "Vorname:", "Kd.-Nr.:", "Geb.-Datum:", "Stra\u00DFe:", "PLZ:", "Stadt:", "Email:", "Telefon:", "Handy:", "Termin:", "Bemerkung:"
            }
        ));
        scrollPaneCustomer.setViewportView(tableCustomer);
```

What is the best way to get all values of the sql statement inside the JTable?

Comment: [`DefaultTableModel.addRow(Vector row)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow-java.util.Vector-). You can get this table model by `((DefaultTableModel) JTable.getModel())`.

Comment: Yes I already read this information. How can I push all data of the ResultSet to a vector? Isn't it better to use an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, an intermediate ArrayList of instances of your data object would be best. First read the resultset into an ArrayList of data objects, then pass this array list on to your presentation layer. Then in your presentation layer, loop the array list, create a Vector or an Object[] to contain the row values (i.e. a Vector or Object[] per data object) and add those Vector or Object[] using the addRow method.

Comment: `Isn't it better to use an ArrayList?` - does the DefaultTableModel have a method that uses an ArrayList?

Comment: @TT., no you should not first read all the data into an ArrayList and then copy the data to the DefaultTableModel. That is a waste of resources. Just create the Vector and add it to the TableModel. If you don't want to use the DefaultTableModel then you can create a custom TableModel that uses an ArrayList to hold the data as demonstrated in [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/).

Comment: @camickr I wouldn't really read data in a format that is tied to a UI. A vector isn't really the best container for object data. I'd prefer reading the data into objects in the data layer, then unpack in the presentation layer.

Comment: Actually I didn't get it... Which return parameter/datatype must my getCustomerData function get? How can I push the received data in my updateCustomerTable function in the rows? Iterate ArrayList or Vector into the addRows function of my DefaultTableModel

Comment: There are multiple ways, depending on your architecture or requirements to do it "the right way". Easiest would be to read the data in a `Vector<Vector<Object>>` and set it directly as the underlying dataVector of your DefaultTableModel ([`DefaulTableModel.setDataVector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setDataVector-java.util.Vector-java.util.Vector-)). Afterwards call [fireTableDataChanged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged--)

Comment: @TT: Can you please try to update my gives source code with your mentioned optimazions?

Comment: Did you get something out of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave you with an example that shows how you can fill the table. It's all wrapped in one MCVE, things like the `Person` class and the `PersonModel` class should exist as top-level classes.

Look at the `readData` method and see it as the method you have that reads the data. It should return the data as a list that can be set as the data container of the table model. In this case the PersonModel stores the data in a generic `List<Person>`. The `readData` method in this example is lazy in that it returns a simple `Arrays.asList` which returns a `List<>` wrapper around an array (i.e. it's fixed size). You will probably want to return an `ArrayList` from your data-reading method if you want to add/remove rows from the UI.

You can find more details on this way of working in `@camickr`'s article he already posted as a comment, [here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/).

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class JTableFillExample {

    private static class Person {
        int id;
        String firstName;
        String surName;
        Date birthDate;
        String address;

        public Person( int id, String firstName, String surName, Date birthDate, String address ) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.surName = surName;
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
            this.address = address;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class PersonModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private List<Person> dataContainer;

        private static String[] columnNames = {
            "ID",
            "First Name",
            "Surname",
            "Birth Date",
            "Address"
        };

        public PersonModel() {
            dataContainer = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public PersonModel(List<Person> dataContainer) {
            this.dataContainer = dataContainer;
        }

        public void setDataContainer(List<Person> dataContainer) {
            this.dataContainer = dataContainer;
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return dataContainer.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Person p = dataContainer.get(rowIndex);
            switch(columnIndex) {
                case 0: return p.id;
                case 1: return p.firstName;
                case 2: return p.surName;
                case 3: return p.birthDate;
                case 4: return p.address;
                default: return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch(columnIndex) {
                case 0: return Integer.class;
                case 3: return Date.class;
                default: return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Person p = dataContainer.get(rowIndex);
            switch(columnIndex) {
                case 0: p.id = (Integer) aValue; break;
                case 1: p.firstName = (String) aValue; break;
                case 2: p.surName = (String) aValue; break;
                case 3: p.birthDate = (Date) aValue; break;
                case 4: p.address = (String) aValue; break;
            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }

    private static Component createTable() {
        return new JTable( new PersonModel() );
    }

    protected static JFrame createFrame() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel( );
        p.setLayout( new BorderLayout( ) );
        p.add( new JScrollPane( createTable( ) ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
        p.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 400, 100 ) );

        JFrame f = new JFrame( );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        f.setContentPane( p );
        f.pack( );
        return f;
    }

    private static List<Person> readData() {
        return Arrays.asList (
            new Person( 1, "Tom", "T", new GregorianCalendar(1975,7,15).getTime(), "Somewhere in Ghent City"),
            new Person( 2, "Jack", "N", new GregorianCalendar(1951,5,13).getTime(), "Somewhere in the States"),
            new Person( 3, "Madonna", "H", new GregorianCalendar(1960,1,19).getTime(), "Somewhere in the States as well")
        );
    }

    private static void readDataAndFillTable(JTable tbl) {
        ((PersonModel) tbl.getModel()).setDataContainer(readData());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = createFrame(); 
                f.setVisible(true);

                final JTable tbl = (JTable) ((JScrollPane) f.getContentPane().getComponent(0)).getViewport().getView();

                Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() { // fill the table after a second
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        readDataAndFillTable(tbl);
                    }
                });
                t.setRepeats(false);
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have done this previously is for student details, in the code below I have created a table for each class in my sql database. There are two methods below, one getting all of the details from the database and one filling the data into a JTable, I have got my connection in another method too.

```
    public void alldet(){
JFrame frame = new JFrame("All Details");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());    
JButton back = new JButton("Back");
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
model.addColumn("Name");
model.addColumn("Surname");
model.addColumn("Gender");
model.addColumn("Target");
model.addColumn("Grade");
model.addColumn("Class");
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JTable table2 = new JTable(model);
JTable table3 = new JTable(model);
filldata(table, "details");
filldata(table2, "details2");
filldata(table3, "details3");
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(519, 350));
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
panel.add(scrollPane);

panel.add(back, "dock south");
frame.add(panel);
frame.setSize(519,405);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(true);
panel.repaint();
frame.setVisible(true);
back.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    frame.hide();
});
    }
public void filldata(JTable table, String type){
    try
{
    Connection conn = Connect();
    if(!Main.teachclass.equals("All")){
        Query = "SELECT name,surname,gender,target,grades,class FROM "+type+" WHERE class = ?";
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
        statement.setString(1, Main.teachclass);
}else{
    Query = "SELECT name,surname,gender,target,grades,class FROM "+type;
    statement = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
}
ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery();
int columns = res.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while(res.next())
{
    Object[] row = new Object[columns];
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        row[i - 1] = res.getObject(i);
    }
    ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(res.getRow() - 1, row);
}

res.close();
statement.close();
conn.close();
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
}
```